# Adding alkyl group to benzene with a deactivating group

Tags: organic-chemistry

**question:**

The question is asking whether we can simply do Friedel-Crafts alkylation to a benzene bonded to a deactivating group (i.e. sulfonic acid group in this problem).

(No answers to this problem)

**attempt:**

I am thinking this reaction cannot work. This is because:

$\ce{R-SO3H}$ **strongly** deactivates the benzene, making the $\ce{C=C}$ bond less nucleophilic. Therefore, it does not have enough 'power' to attack the carbocation complex ($\ce{CH3CH2-FeBr3}$), which is a limitation in Friedel-Crafts reactions.

Therefore, my attempt is:

1. de-sulfonation: dil. $\ce{H2SO4}$ + $\ce{H2O}$, make it to benzene
2. Friedel-Crafts acylation: $\ce{CH3COCl}$ + $\ce{AlCl3}$ (catalyst), make it to acetophenone
3. sulfonation: conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$, make it to 3-Acetylbenzenesulfonic acid
4. Clemmensen reaction: make it to product

**question 1:**

Are there any quicker ways to perform this synthesis? I am thinking is there any way to make the group less deactivating, hence allow the alkylation to happen, but no idea how.

**question 2:**

Although Clemmensen reaction is a good and common choice, it uses highly-toxic mercury. However, for Wolff–Kishner reduction, I am worrying that high temperature will decompose the product, plus the base will neutralize the product acid. Overall, which reaction is better for this particular reduction step?
[image]

Comment: I found a Chinese patent via Chem. Absts. that claims a 50% yield of the acetophenone by FC of benzenesulfonic acid. The conditions of a Clemmensen may effect desulfonation.

Comment: @user55119 Thanks. Can I say the -SO3H group is not that strong in the deactivation of the benzene ring *in general*, or just particularly in this reaction? Also, do you mean HCl used in Clemmensen will undergo desulfonation? If yes, is thioketal reduction is best choice?

Comment: Because a ring is deactivated doesn't mean it is unreactive but rather slower to react than an activated ring. I am not saying that the HCl will cause desulfonation but it may. Reduction of a thioketal with Ni(R) is an option. Also, reduce carbonyl to secondary alcohol and hydrogenolize the hydroxyl group with H2 and Pd/C.